# Firebase with Angular 6 does not redirect to index.html

Tags: angular, firebase, routes, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular 6 application deployed to Firebase, however, when I go to the url which I have deployed my application to, it does not redirect to index.html. It only shows the view documentation page.

However, if I type the address with /index.html in the end, it works flawlessly.

Here is my firebase json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my angular routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'add-recipe', component: AddrecipeComponent },
  { path: 'edit-recipe/:id', component: EditrecipeComponent },
  { path: 'recipe-detail/:id',      component: RecipedetailComponent },
  { path: 'shopping-list',      component: ShoppinglistComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

And in my index.html file this is my base href:

```
<base href="/">
```

During the configuration, I checked the option that this is a single page application.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: when I test it with localhost, it redirects flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirectTo` should have the value of a `route` i.e. `path` with a '/'.

Change `redirectTo: 'home',` to `redirectTo: '/home',`

Also, I guess the last two segments in the route config are redundant. Please change it to the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'add-recipe', component: AddrecipeComponent },
  { path: 'edit-recipe/:id', component: EditrecipeComponent },
  { path: 'recipe-detail/:id',      component: RecipedetailComponent },
  { path: 'shopping-list',      component: ShoppinglistComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];
```

Comment: It is a fair point, I have changed it as it should be that way, yet it did not solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Please update the question as well with the fix. Also, did you make any changes to `firebase json`?

Comment: I updated the question and I did not make any changes to my firebase.json

Comment: Defining a redirect path instead of a component solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem for anyone who comes across this issue: `HomeComponent` was defined twice in `appRoutes` and although localhost has no problem with it, Firebase did.

According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#remove-duplicate-hero-routes), you should not have duplicate routes defined.

To simply solve the issue, I removed the line

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
```

and it made the problem disappear.

Another way to go by solving this issue is the accepted answer, which is actually a better solution.